# Upload image from Android to WCF service

Tags: android, wcf

I'm looking for a complete example for uploading an image + some text fields from Android to a WCF service. I've been searching for days without finding any useful examples. What I need is the code for **both** the **client** and **server**.

I've been able to make it work with JSON and Base64 encoding the image as a string, but this is way too slow with images around 500KB. What I'm looking for has to be efficient. Probably using a stream.

Can anyone please give me a complete sample code? I've seen a lot of snippets on each side, but not a complete sample. From getting the image from a path on the phone to posting it to the server and consuming it on the server in C#? How to get the image as a bytearray on the server and the text into string variables?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: No way you will get people to code for you here. Ask a specific question and you will get an answer.

Comment: I knew that kind of response would come...I'm not asking for a lot though. This should be possible to do in what, 10-15 loc? I've seen a lot more posted here than that. All I want is a example so I don't have to guess. Is that so bad?

Answer (score 0):

For setting up WCF streaming on the server side see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

You could also try just using basic http binding and MTOM.

For the android part you will need to get help from someone else, sorry.